# Why can't I edit my entity before patching it in cakephp 3.7?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to add a date value to a CakePHP entity before patching it, but it doesn't work. I had to workaround by creating an array and patching it. How can I change my code to manipulate the entity object instead of patching it with an array?

Here is the current code and the code I want to use instead:

```
 //current code  
    $cotacao = $this->Cotacaos->newEntity();
    $dados = $this->request->getData();
    $agora = Time::now();
    $dados['data'] = [
        'year' => $agora->year,
        'month' => $agora->month,
        'day' => $agora->day,
        'hour' => $agora->hour,
        'minute' => $agora->minute
    ];
    $cotacao = $this->Cotacaos->patchEntity($cotacao, $dados);
    if ($this->Cotacaos->save($cotacao)) {
       //etcetera


 //proposed code  
    $cotacao = $this->Cotacaos->newEntity();
    $cotacao->data = Time::now();
    $cotacao = $this->Cotacaos->patchEntity($cotacao, $this->request->getData());
    if ($this->Cotacaos->save($cotacao)) {
       //etcetera
```

The problem is: The date isn't being saved if I do it the second way. =(

Comment: `$cotacao->data = Time::now();`? How is that even supposed to work?

Comment: Sorry for the bad choosing of words for my variables, but in my "cotacao" entity i have a "data" property, it receives a datetime. So currently I'm storing the current datetime in an array and patching it. Couldn't I just set the object directly, instead of feeding an array and patching it?

Comment: Further explaining the line of code you quoted: `$cotacao` is the entity I'm manipulating, `data`is an existing property of the entity, it stores a date, `Time`is a cakephp lib for manipulating date and time, and it's method `now`returns an instance of the moment, like java's Calendar.getInstance(), php's date() etc.

Comment: Does your `$this->request->getData()` have a `data` field in it, by any chance? That would overwrite whatever you're putting there. You might also look into the Timestamp behavior, which can do this for you.

Comment: I'll check both things and get back to you. Thanks Greg!

Comment: Hi @GregSchmidt I'm sorry for taking so long, but my `$this->request->getData()` doesn't have a `data`field, only a `user_id` and a `valor` (value).

I'll check the behavior, but isn't it odd? Maybe `data`is kind of a reserved word in this context of cakephp.